# Deploying wsp from MSI installer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, windows-installer, wsp

I would like to deploy a SharePoint 2010 solution package (wsp) using MSI (or some other user friendly form of installer).

I know I can create a custom action and deploy everything using the SharePoint object model, but I don't think that's the way to go.

What would be the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an upcoming project on it, read about it here:
http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SpecificationV2&referringTitle=Home

Currently, the best way would be to use MSI with CustomAction. But instead of object model, use powershell script to deploy the WSP. It will much cleaner than code.

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/12/02/adding-and-deploying-solutions-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: I think I'll try to modify the sharepointinstaller project for 2010 - it's supposed to be very easy.
Thanks!

Comment: did you make it to modify the sharepoint installer and adapt it to SP2010?